# using tryLock to lock object passed into function

Tags: multithreading

how i can acquire the lock using `tryLock` of the `integer` passed in this way:

```
lock lock = new ReentrantLock();


public void function(Integer i) {
        try{
          if(lock.i.tryLock()){ //-> syntax error
           } 
        }finally{
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant. tryLock is an API for Lock rather than integer and it doesnt have public integer field called i hence compilation error. See whole doc about the same http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();


public void function(Integer i) {
    try{
      if(lock.tryLock()){ //-> syntax error gone
       } 
    }finally{
       lock.unlock();
    }
}
```